# Issue when trying to use doctrine queryBuilder

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have two entities `Categorie` and `ChampCat` with `ManyToMany` relation and I want to get list of categories with related `ChampCat` by using doctrine QueryBuilder so I have used this query:

```
class CategorieRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{
    public function myFindCategories(array $tab){

        $em = $this->getEntityManager();

        $query = $em->select(array('cat', 'ch'))
                    ->from('AnnonceBundle\Entity\Categorie', 'cat')
                    ->join('cat.champsCat', 'ch')
                    ->where('cat.id In (:tabOfIds)')
                    ->setParameter('tabOfIds', array_values($tab))
                    ->getQuery();

        return $query->getResult();

    }


}
```

Here u can see the Categorie Entity:

```
<?php

namespace AnnonceBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Categorie
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="categorie")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AnnonceBundle\Repository\CategorieRepository")
 */
class Categorie implements \JsonSerializable
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="refCat", type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $refCat;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="libelleCat", type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $libelleCat;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AnnonceBundle\Entity\ChampCat",cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $champsCat;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set refCat
     *
     * @param string $refCat
     *
     * @return Categorie
     */
    public function setRefCat($refCat)
    {
        $this->refCat = $refCat;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get refCat
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRefCat()
    {
        return $this->refCat;
    }

    /**
     * Set libelleCat
     *
     * @param string $libelleCat
     *
     * @return Categorie
     */
    public function setLibelleCat($libelleCat)
    {
        $this->libelleCat = $libelleCat;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get libelleCat
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLibelleCat()
    {
        return $this->libelleCat;
    }

    /**
     * Set champsCat
     *
     * @param \AnnonceBundle\Entity\ChampCat $champsCat
     *
     * @return Categorie
     */
    public function setChampsCat(\AnnonceBundle\Entity\ChampCat $champsCat = null)
    {
        $this->champsCat = $champsCat;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get champsCat
     *
     * @return \AnnonceBundle\Entity\ChampCat
     */
    public function getChampsCat()
    {
        return $this->champsCat;
    }
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->champsCat = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add champsCat
     *
     * @param \AnnonceBundle\Entity\ChampCat $champsCat
     *
     * @return Categorie
     */
    public function addChampsCat(\AnnonceBundle\Entity\ChampCat $champsCat)
    {
        $this->champsCat[] = $champsCat;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove champsCat
     *
     * @param \AnnonceBundle\Entity\ChampCat $champsCat
     */
    public function removeChampsCat(\AnnonceBundle\Entity\ChampCat $champsCat)
    {
        $this->champsCat->removeElement($champsCat);
    }

    function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return get_object_vars($this);
    }
}
```

And this is ChamCat Entity:

```
<?php

namespace AnnonceBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * ChampCat
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="champ_cat")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AnnonceBundle\Repository\ChampCatRepository")
 */
class ChampCat implements \JsonSerializable
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     *@var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="refCh", type="string")
     */
    private $refCh;



    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nom_ch", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nomCh;

    /**
     * @var bool
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="app_ch", type="boolean")
     */
    private $appCh;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="format_ch", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $formatCh;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->refCh;
    }

    /**
     * Set refCh
     *
     * @param integer $refCh
     * @return ChampCat
     */
    public function setRefCh($refCh)
    {
        $this->refCh = $refCh;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get refCh
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getRefCh()
    {
        return $this->refCh;
    }

    /**
     * Set nomCh
     *
     * @param string $nomCh
     * @return ChampCat
     */
    public function setNomCh($nomCh)
    {
        $this->nomCh = $nomCh;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nomCh
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getNomCh()
    {
        return $this->nomCh;
    }

    /**
     * Set appCh
     *
     * @param boolean $appCh
     * @return ChampCat
     */
    public function setAppCh($appCh)
    {
        $this->appCh = $appCh;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get appCh
     *
     * @return boolean 
     */
    public function getAppCh()
    {
        return $this->appCh;
    }

    /**
     * Set formatCh
     *
     * @param string $formatCh
     * @return ChampCat
     */
    public function setFormatCh($formatCh)
    {
        $this->formatCh = $formatCh;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get formatCh
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getFormatCh()
    {
        return $this->formatCh;
    }

    function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return get_object_vars($this);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this query didn't work, so what am I missing ?

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't work" it has an error, or fals results?

Comment: I'm using this query via ajax function and the result is "500 (Internal Server Error)" wich means that there is a problem in the query.

Comment: Yes can you give us the Exception message? it is in your project app/log

Comment: Oh sorry didn't know about this file :). And this is the exception:
[2016-08-09 11:14:10] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception RuntimeException: "No alias was set before invoking getRootAlias()." at /var/www/sbc_project/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/QueryBuilder.php line 423 {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0): No alias was set before invoking getRootAlias(). at /var/www/sbc_project/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/QueryBuilder.php:423)"} []

Answer (score 0):

Is it working with this syntax?

```
public function myFindCategories(array $tab){

    if(count($tab) == 0) return []; //or IN() will bug with an empty array


    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('cat')
                ->addSelect('ch')
                ->innerJoin('cat.champsCat', 'ch')
                ->where('cat.id in (:tabOfIds)')
                ->setParameter('tabOfIds', $tab)
                ->getQuery();

    return $query->getResult();

}
```

Comment: no sorry this is not working. The problem is not in the $tab variable because it's never emty to test it, but I think there is a problem in the query syntax but I'm not sure about it.

Comment: If you are in your repository class, an you try like my edited answer?( without the $em call?)

Comment: Thank you it's working but I can't find th ChampCat entity inside the Categories list ! This is the result [{"id":2,"refCat":"002","libelleCat":"cat2","champsCat":{}}], chamsCat is empty !

Comment: Maybe this is due to lazy loading. What do you get with `$cat->getChampsCat() `?

Comment: I thought about that but actualy I'm not sending the object to twig directly (so I can use the lazy loading) but I'm using ajax so result will be ajax, something like that: [{"id":2,"refCat":"002","libelleCat":"cat2","champsCat":{}}]. So when I loop throught it  the lazy loading will not work.